# python socket protocol not support

Tags: python, sockets, can-bus

I useed python-can-isotp on RaspberryPi3, and test it with example code, but I got an error.

My simple code:

```
import isotp

s = isotp.socket()
s2 = isotp.socket()
# Configuring the sockets.
s.set_fc_opts(stmin=5, bs=10)
#s.set_general_opts(...)
#s.set_ll_opts(...)

s.bind("vcan0" rxid=0x123 txid=0x456)  # We love named parameters!
s2.bind("vcan0", rxid=0x456, txid=0x123)
s2.send(b"Hello, this is a long payload sent in small chunks of 8 bytes.")
print(s.recv())
```

ERROR:

`File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.7.0/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
OSError: [Errno 93] Protocol not supported`

Can someone please help me find the solution to the problem?

Comment: Did you read the instructions for installing/troubleshooting that module?  There's a kernel module that has to be installed for it to work.

Comment: Thank you, I did ignore that troubleshooting.

Comment: when I 'sudo insmod ./net/can/can-isotp.ko', another error occurred 'insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./net/can/can-isotp.ko: Unknown symbol in module', but I don't know which symbol is unknow, How to solve this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: A module must be built explicitly for the kernel version on which you're attempting to insert it (possible failure cause #1). Also, generally, one should use `modprobe` to cause a kernel module to be inserted as, unlike `insmod`, it also handles module dependencies (possible cause #2). I believe the `dmesg` command (which dumps the kernel message buffer) will show you the symbol that caused `insmod` to fail.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I solved this problem.

Comment: Out of curisosity, what CAN interface and linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/hartkopp/can-isotp) (with slight modifications) to make `isotp` work on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with the latest Raspbian Stretch.

Here is the exact sequence of commands I carried out:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
git clone https://github.com/hartkopp/can-isotp.git
cd can-isotp
sudo apt install build-essential raspberrypi-kernel-headers
make install
sudo make modules_install
modprobe can
sudo insmod ./net/can/can-isotp.ko
```

However, I don't use it in Python. I simply tested the tools provided for use with `isotp`, such as e.g. `isotpsend` and `isotprecv`.

Comment: Hi,I have another question, when I `sudo apt install build-essential raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, the kernel-headers version is different between `/lib/modules/(kernel-headers-version)` with `$(uname -r)`

Comment: As far as I can tell after installation there should be the appropriate version of the kernel headers in `/usr/src`. Do the headers installed there not fit to your kernel from `uname -r`? In my case both fit together: `4.14.69-v7+`

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I solved the python-can-isotp problem, and then I will focus on the problem of headers version.